# Create a function that takes a UIViewController as a parameter

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I'm trying to create a function that takes a UIViewController as a function.  The reason for this is that there are multiple custom viewcontrollers that it can be passed.  Here is my current function, which works but uses a switch statement and enum:

```
enum controllerTypes {
    case First, Second
}

extension UIViewController {

    func presentViewController(storyBoardName: String, storyBoardIdentifier: String, controllerType: controllerTypes, completion:(() -> Void)?) {

        switch controllerType {

        case .First:
            let firstVC = UIStoryboard(name: storyBoardName, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyBoardIdentifier) as? FirstViewController
            if let firVC = firstVC {
                self.present(firVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        case .Second:
            let secondVC = UIStoryboard(name: storyBoardName, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyBoardIdentifier) as? SecondViewController
            if let secVC = secondVC {
                self.present(secVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
        completion?()
    }
}
```

instead of passing the 'controllerTypes' enum for the parameter I want to pass it any type of UIViewController, when I try and do this I get below error:

```
        func presentViewController(storyBoardName: String, storyBoardIdentifier: String, controllerType: UIViewController, completion:(() -> Void)?) {
            let sampleVC = UIStoryboard(name: storyBoardName, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyBoardIdentifier) as? controllerType//error - use of undeclared type 'controllerType'
            if let samVC = sampleVC {
                self.present(samVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
}
```

Any idea if its possible to do this?

Comment: Do you assign any values according to the type of the VC or simply present ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan as of now its just presenting

Comment: I'm hoping to use a parameter that takes in the UIViewController it will present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make your function generic and then cast to the generic parameter type:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func presentViewController<T: UIViewController>(storyBoardName: String, storyBoardIdentifier: String, controllerType: T.Type, completion:(() -> Void)?) {
        let sampleVC = UIStoryboard(name: storyBoardName, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyBoardIdentifier) as? T
        if let samVC = sampleVC {
            self.present(samVC, animated: true, completion: completion)
        }
    }
}
```